# How to change the default location for File Open in VLC?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, vlc-media-player

I want to change the default location for FILE OPEN in vLC media player Version 3.1. I think it is in preferences but cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to change what is displayed in the Filename section but other than that, that is controlled by Windows File Dialog, not really by VLC.
Though after some checking, VLC does seem to write a string named **lastVisited** inside 
**Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QtProject\OrganizationDefaults\FileDialog** with last opened file and nothing else from there.
Modifying it defaults it to **file:///C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC** after VLC Media Player re-launch, I guess you'll have to leave this one alone for now.

Answer (score 1):

What I do to set the default directory (currently running 3.0.4 Vetinari under Windows 7) is:

1. Open VLC
2. Media > Open Folder > [select folder]
3. Close VLC and reopen

Doing this sets the registry as described by @Nurudin Imsirovic.  Yes, it's bit awkward, but it works.  Would be nice to have a setting for this under something like Tools > Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

VLC uses the default Windows Save / Open location;
usually `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` (a.k.a. “My Documents”).

In Windows Vista, 7, 8, and 8.1 you can change this by right clicking on the Documents Library in Explorer, Proprieties. There you will be able to add new locations, remove and set a default save location. The default save location is also the default open location.

In Windows 10 (prior to version 1703) you go to Settings -> System -> Storage -> Save Locations

In Windows 10 (version 1703 or later) Settings -> System -> Storage -> Change where new content is saved.